# Swift UIEdgeInsets not working properly, how to add spacing between cells?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I want to add spacing between multiple custom cells. I have multiple sections that contains the cells.

I have a ViewController class for the UITableView where I specify the information:

```
struct customCell {
        let title: String
} 

 func configure() {
            models.append(Section(title: "", options: [
             customCell(title: "Sounds"){
            },
}
```

And I have a different UITableViewCell class where I use the layoutSubViews() method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
      
        contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0))
```

I see other solutions on this website, where they get the spacing by using UIEdgeInsets.

I tried using the layoutSubViews() method but that didn't work, it pushes the content of the cell upwards instead of adding spaces between cells:

[image: example]

When I use all insets:

```
contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top:15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15))
```

The content gets pushed inwards from all sides:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot add space between cells. But you can easily make it _look_ as if there is space between cells.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10))
}
```

And the other solution can be that if you use UIView in your contentView and declare other objects in that View, it will behave like you add space between cell.

Comment: Ok! Thanks, I found where I was mistaken

Comment: With your code I have the same problem, the content is now pushed inwards from all the sides.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set nagative value for inset, like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -10, right: 0))
}
```

Comment: I also tried that and unfortunately it doesn't work.